# Unicodedecode Error when pushing to CouchDB: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9

Tags: encoding, couchdb, couchapp

I am using couchdb and couchapp on windows. 
I'm working on an ongoing project of a professor https://github.com/Hypertopic/Tire-a-part. I'm currently trying  to set up the app on my computer.

When I do:

```
couchapp push http://127.0.0.1:5984/tire-a-part
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "couchapp\dispatch.pyc", line 48, in dispatch
File "couchapp\dispatch.pyc", line 92, in _dispatch
File "couchapp\commands.pyc", line 79, in push
File "couchapp\localdoc.pyc", line 123, in push
File "couchapp\client.pyc", line 294, in save_doc
File "json\__init__.pyc", line 231, in dumps
File "json\encoder.pyc", line 201, in encode
File "json\encoder.pyc", line 264, in iterencode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: 
invalid continuation byte
```

My professor and my friends all have mac and don't have this problem.
After a few hours on the net trying to search for similar problems I understand that it is an encoding error but i don't understand what is not correctly encoded and what should I do.
Thanks

Edit: I have discovered the debug option of couchapp. It gives much more detail but i still don't really understand as it is my first time with couchapp and couchdb. This is the last part of the debug as i don't think the begining is important:

```
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] push spec/samples/scopus.bib
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] push spec/spec_helper.rb
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Resource uri: http://127.0.0.1:5984/tire-a-part
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Request: GET _design/Tire-a-part
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'User- 
Agent': 'couchapp/0.7.5'}
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Params: {}
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Start to perform request: GET 127.0.0.1:5984 
/tire-a-part/_design/Tire-a-part
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Send headers: ['GET /tire-a-part/_design/Tire-a- 
part HTTP/1.1\r\n', 'Host: 127.0.0.1:5984\r\n', 'User-Agent: 
restkit/3.0.4\r\n', 'Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n', 'Accept: 
application/json\r\n']
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Start to parse response
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] Got response: 404 Object Not Found
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] headers: [MultiDict([('X-CouchDB-Body- 
Time','0'),('X-Couch-Request-ID', '5ab9eee6cb'), ('Server', 'CouchDB/2.1.1 
(Erlang OTP/18)'), ('Date', 'Sat, 14 Apr 2018 10:42:16 GMT'), ('Content- 
Type','application/json'), ('Content-Length', '41'), ('Cache-Control', 
'must-revalidate')])]
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] return response class
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] release connection
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [DEBUG] C:\Users\jules\Desktop\LO10 projet\Tire-a- 
part\vendor don't exist
2018-04-14 12:42:16 [CRITICAL] 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in 
position 
1: invalid continuation byte
```

I compared this with what my friend got on mac and it is the exact same except for the [CRITICAL] line. after the 'vendordon't exist' couchapp put _design/Tire-a-part

Comment: Do your classmates get the same `404 Not Found` response?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be normal

Comment: I'm on Linux, so I cannot reproduce your problem on Windows. But I'm trying to see if `tire-a-part` works fine on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but I tried something: I started a Python3.5 command line, and declared a variable `byte='\xe9'` and then printed the variable with `print(byte)`. As can be seen below, the `0xe9` byte looks like to be the `é` character:

```
$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> byte='\xe9'
>>> print(byte)
é
>>>
```

I'm not sure why Windows has problem with the `é` character but macOS works fine.

---

On Linux shell command-line, when I put the `é` character in a file and take a hex-dump of the file, I see that the `é` character is actually equal to `c3 a9`, notice that the `0a` is the `new-line` or `line-feed`:

```
$ echo 'é' > file
$ cat file 
é
$ hd file 
00000000  c3 a9 0a                                          |...|
00000003
```

Therefore, I think the problem is that the `é` character is encoded with one byte of `0xe9` rather than two bytes of `0xc3 0xa9`.

---

I played around with Go to see where the `e9` comes from and I notice that the Unicode for `é` is actually `\u00e9` and it is corresponding the two bytes of `\xc3\xa9` i.e. `0xc3` and `0xa9`, as shown below. Therefore, on your Windows machine, somehow the Unicode is mixed up with the hexadecimal bytes.

[image]

Comment: I've seen people with the same problem as me on the net and the problem was that a file was badly encoded latin-1 instead of utf-8 i believe. But here i don't know which file cause a problem and if i can change the encoding. I will probly ask my professor about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really seem it was an encoding error of 'é'. There were 2 files with 'é' in their name. After changing it to 'e' the push command work. The app don't work but that's a story for another day....